# How To retrieve ArrayField data in django query?

Tags: python, django, postgresql-9.3

I have a model with an ArrayField as:

```
class Item:
static_data             =   ArrayField(
                                   models.CharField(max_length=120), 
                                   blank=True
                            )
```

Now I want to retrieve only the First Element of the Array in a select query using django model.

I want to access it in values_list method.

Is it possible to do so? If its possible how do I achieve it.

Comment: try adding .first() at the last of you query

Answer (score 0):

in the Django shell

```
YourModel.objects.all().first()
```

or

```
def get_first_element(MyModel):
    my_query =  your query //may return multiple results
    return my_query[:1]
```

***:)***

Comment: first is used for retrieving the first queryset object. I want to access the first element of the arrayfield in the values_list method

Answer (score 0):

Using below query to fetch first element of the array model field

```
Item.objects.filter(submit_candidate={'static_data':value})
```

you can [read the documentation](https://djongo.readthedocs.io/docs/using-django-with-mongodb-data-fields/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

`Item.objects.values_list("static_data__0__200")` will retrieve you indexes 0 through 200 of the static_data array